# MySQL concat result of two selects

Tags: mysql, sql, database, concatenation

I am using the following query in MySQL two sum a field in two tables into one figure:

```
SELECT 
(SELECT sum(number)
FROM table1 
WHERE mydate IS NOT NULL) +
(SELECT sum(number)
FROM table2 
WHERE mydate IS NOT NULL)
AS sumOfTheTwo
```

This is working fine and **sumOfTheTwo** is giving me my correct result.

The problem is, is that I want to output this number as currency.
Normally I would use the following:

```
concat("$", format(sumOfTheTwo, 2))
```

I can't figure out how I would do it in this case.
Could anyone suggest anything?

Thanks!

**EDIT / SOLUTION:**

As: Oto Shavadze showed, the following resolved this:

```
SELECT concat("$", format( 

(SELECT sum(number)
FROM table1 
WHERE mydate IS NOT NULL) +
(SELECT sum(number)
FROM table2 
WHERE mydate IS NOT NULL)

, 2)) as res
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT concat("$", format( 

    (SELECT sum(number)
    FROM table1 
    WHERE mydate IS NOT NULL) +
    (SELECT sum(number)
    FROM table2 
    WHERE mydate IS NOT NULL)

, 2)) as res
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the MySQL [string format functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html). [`FORMAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_format), [`CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) and [`CONCAT_WS()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws) in particular.

`FORMAT` lets you convert a string into a number, while `CONCAT` will be use to append a currency symbol.

Answer (score 1):

You must `Concat` in first block I try this and worked for me:

```
SELECT 

 concat("$", format(
    (
    -- block 1
    (SELECT sum(number)
    FROM table1 
    WHERE mydate IS NOT NULL) +
    -- block 2
    (SELECT sum(number)
    FROM table2 
    WHERE mydate IS NOT NULL)

     ), 2))

AS sumOfTheTwo ;
```

it so simple.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `concat()` with your current query:

```
SELECT 
concat('$', (SELECT sum(number)
FROM table1 
WHERE mydate IS NOT NULL) +
(SELECT sum(number)
FROM table2 
WHERE mydate IS NOT NULL))
AS sumOfTheTwo
```

Pls note that it may be a lot more efficient to perform this formatting in the application logic, rather than in sql.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT CONCAT('$',((SELECT sum(number)
FROM table1 
WHERE mydate IS NOT NULL) +
(SELECT sum(number)
 FROM table2 
 WHERE mydate IS NOT NULL)));
```

Comment: Though this might answer the question, please also add a short explanation what your code does and why it solves the initial problem.

Answer (score 0):

In sql server i have an example :

```
 SELECT 
 '$'+
cast((SELECT 1) + (SELECT 2) as varchar(50)) AS sumOfTheTwo
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [concate()](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-concat-function.php) with first `select` and use [format()](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mathematical-functions/mysql-mathematical-format.php) to add number of zeros after decimal(.) . 2 in `formate()` indicates 2 zero after decimal.

```
select concat("$", format(
(SELECT sum(number) FROM table1 WHERE mydate IS NOT NULL) + 
(SELECT sum(number) FROM table1 WHERE mydate IS NOT NULL), 2)) 
as sumOfTheTwo`
```